# user-locale association/relation - foreign key on locale code?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: `Users` and `Locales`.

```
Locales(id, name, code)
```

Locales.name is a english name of locale ('Spanish' for example) and Locales.code is a 5 char code of locale ('en_us' for example). Each user should have one locale. I thought about 2 options:

1. Users table will have `LocaleId` column as FK to `Locales.id`.
2. Users table will have `locale (string)` column as FK to `Locales.code` column

Which approach will be better? Note that I will have to search for users in some locale, perform some joins on other tables on locale field etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table, you have an (I assume) system-generated value in ID. This is your surrogate key. However, you also have a natural key value in Code. Yes, you can define a unique constraint on Code so foreign keys can refer to it. But if you do that, why not just go ahead and make it your primary key in the first place?

There continues to be a very long-standing debate on this issue.

One side comes down on the if-it's-good-in-most-cases-it-must-be-good-in-all-cases side of the issue and demands that all tables have a surrogate key.

I don't agree. Let's see what happens if you chuck the ID field altogether and make Code the PK of the table.

On the plus side:

1. The key value itself will be meaningful to almost all who see it. So a look at the Users table will be enough to tell what language they prefer. Is there anyone but my Grandmother who doesn't know "en_us" from "en_gb"? So a lot of times, you won't even have to join to the Locales table -- you already have enough information in most cases.
2. You've eliminated an extra field from your table. Simplification without sacrificing function is always good.
3. Generating a guaranteed unique value for every insert does require some system overhead. In this case, this will not be significant as once you've populated the Locales table, it should be very stable.

On the minus side:

1. Joining via a numeric value is slightly more efficient than a character string. The difference is minuscule but there.
2. How much can you rely on Microsoft to hold the current values steady and make no changes, maybe change "en_gb" to "en_uk" or something like that? Once you've established references to a key value, changing that value can be quite a challenge.
3. Even if you are certain that existing values won't change, could future values exceed 5 characters? This isn't really an inherent disadvantage of the practice, just your particular implementation. :)
4. Surrogates (generally integer) tend to be smaller than natural keys (generally strings). While you have one less column in your key table, you may have larger FK columns in referencing tables.

So which is better for your particular situation?

I have no idea.

You and your team will have to weigh the pros and cons to make your own decision.